# Significance of measure of dispersion in Orbit determination output

Tags: low-earth-orbit, measurement, orbit-determination, accuracy

I am trying to understand the significance of specifying dispersion measure of ***3 sigma*** or ***½ sigma*** along with Orbit determination output. I am assuming a ***Space Craft*** in LEO sun-synchronous orbit of around 900 km having on-board GPS receiver.  When  do we prefer to specify 3 sigma instead of 2 sigma and vice versa ? Similarly when should we prefer to use 1 sigma instead of either 2 sigma or 3 sigma?

Comment: This depends upon the purpose of the software producing the orbit determination output. It will help people to answer this question if you can provide this context information. Is this an orbit determination to help ground stations point their antenna, for collision avoidance, something else? What type of organisation owns and is using the software? e.g. is it the satellite operator, a tracking station, SSA telescope, regulator?

Comment: @Puffin the question is academic oriented and more related to the satellite operator tracking the Spacecraft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all about choosing how much tolerance you have for uncertainty.  The more sigmas you use, the higher your confidence becomes that the object is within that many standard deviations of the estimated point, and the bigger the region grows.  You can select any number you want, from a large volume with a large probability to a small volume with a small probability, but the exact formulas for the specific percentage vary with the error distribution you assume, and the number of dimensions you're working in.

The specific probabilities that almost everyone thinks of as matching are 1 sigma = 68.27%, 2 sigma = 95.45%, and 3 sigma = 99.73%, but that's only strictly true for "normally distributed" (Gaussian) errors, which is an extremely common assumption, but also just one dimension, which is only the case in orbits if you are solving for only one direction at a time.  When solving for three variables simultaneously, the number of sigmas that give those percentages are 1.88, 2.83, and 3.77; when solving for six (Keplerian elements, or position and velocity together), the numbers are 2.65, 3.58, and 4.48.  These numbers come from the [chi-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) ($\chi^2$) distribution, which is the sum of the squares of some number (usually written with Greek letter nu: $\nu$) of Gaussians, and thus gives the squared length of a random vector in $\nu$ dimensions.

Gaussian errors are usually assumed because they are easy to work with, and there is reasonable theoretical justification ([central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) / [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)), but those are only strictly true in the limit of making a huge number of measurements.  Practical systems have a lot less information available, and can show behavior quite different than Gaussian, but still, out of habit, tradition, and the greater difficulty of working with less familiar distributions, most people usually stick with the "normal" one.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Just one doubt. Why do the errors follow Gaussian distribution ?

Comment: @Soumajit  because it makes them easy to work with, they have decent theoretical foundations, they are good enough much of the time, and they are traditional.

Comment: thanks once again.